# how to find the length of the string java

Tags: java, string

I just started learning Java...

I need to input a txt. full of words and then output a histogram listing out the frequency by the length of the words.

e.g.Length      0  1  2  3  4    //

Frequency   0  20 6  1  0    //

```
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception  {
         if(args.length == 0) {
             System.out.println("blablabla");
          }

        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( args[0] ) );
        String[] wordList = new String[10]; // store the words
        int[] histogram = new int[5];// frequency counters
        int wordCnt = 0;

        while (inFile.ready()) {

        String word = inFile.readLine();

            if ( word.length == wordCnt) {
                histogram[wordCnt]++;
            }

            if (wordCnt == wordList.length){
                wordList = doubleTheArray(wordList);
            }

        wordList[wordCnt++] = word;
        }

        inFile.close();

        wordList=trim(wordList);
```

**Q1:** I'm not sure if I should put `wordList=trim(wordList);` in front of `inFile.close();`

```
        System.out.printf( "List contains %d Strings.\n",wordList.length);
        System.out.println("LEN\tFREQ");
        for ( int i = 0; i < histogram.length ; ++i) //
            System.out.printf( "%2d\t%d\n",i,histogram[i] );
    } // END MAIN
```

**Q2:** I have trouble getting `histogram[i]`. Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun no idea how to find the lengths of every words in `wordList`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like trimming `inFile.readLine()` makes more sense.

Could you please show us where you populate `histogram` array?

Comment: I can't get `histogram` though... Can you help me with that first?

Comment: Do you mean the concept of histogram? In that case check out TheLostMind's answer. Though I suggest googling it too.

Comment: No...I know what histogram is. I have a hard time getting `histogram` into the code. I don't know how to get the length of each words, since they are in a String[].

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is :

```
1.  Use a HashMap with (length, count) as key and value respectively..
2.  Read all the words from the file, for each word read, check the length.
3. if length of word already exists as key in the HashMap, increment the count value of hashMap else add the length as key and set its value (count ) to 1. This approach would simplify things..
```

Answer (score 0):

***Repair:***

Q1)

```
while (true) {
    String word = inFile.readLine();
    if (word == null) {
        break
    }
    word = word.trim();
```

Q2)

If `histogram[i]` is the count of all words with length `i`, then

```
        if ( word.length == wordCnt) {
            histogram[wordCnt]++;
        }
```

should probably be

```
        if (word.length() < histogram.length) { // Only limited length counted.
            histogram[word.length()]++;
        }
```

For arrays `String[]` there is a count field `.length`. For `String` there is a method called `.length()`. *By the way, a field and a method may have the same name in a class; not that it is good style, as fields should be substantives ("length") or adjectives ("empty"), and methods verbs ("isEmpty", "getLength").*

---

Let's jump into the deep.

```
    int totalWordCount = 0;
    Map<String, Integer> histogram = new TreeMap<>(); // Word to count map.
    // Implement histogram as TreeMap, which is sorted by key.

    try (BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
        for (;;) {
            String line = inFile.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            String[] words = line.split("\\W+"); // Split by non-word chars.
            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }
                ++totalWordCount;
                Integer wordCount = histogram.get(word);
                int wc = wordCount == null ? 0 : wordCount.intValue();
                histogram.put(word, wc + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Histogram:");
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : histogram.entrySet()) {
        double frequency = ((double)entry.getValue().intValue()) / totalWordCount;
        System.out.printf("%-20s %1.6f%n", entry.getKey(), frequency);
    }
```

1. A Map from word to count will do nicely. To have the words (keys) sorted implement it as TreeMap, otherwise one normally takes a HashMap.
2. As of Java 7, the construction `try (DECLARATIONS) {` will allways call `close()`.
3. readLine yielding the line without line-ending; null means end-of-file.
4. split can be used to pick the words. `\\w` would match a word char, `\\W` a non-word char; postfix `+` one or more. The empty string can happen, when the line starts with a non-word char. So you need to skip the empty string.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, but I have not learnt this yet...Can you please take a look at my code and give me some advises? :)